# Would a planet with mirror surface emit radiation due to dynamical Casimir effect? If so, where the energy would come from?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, vacuum, casimir-effect

[The dynamical casimir effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casimir_effect#Dynamical_Casimir_effect) tells that an accelerating mirror should produce photons. Due to equivalence principle a mirror in uniform gravitational field also should produce photons. So, should a planet covered with mirror radiate and if so, where the energy should come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the abstract of Fulling & Davies [paper from 1976](https://doi.org/10.1098/rspa.1976.0045) (it is cited in Wikipedia article linked in the OP):

> A uniformly accelerating mirror does not radiate.

So a static mirrored planet also would not be radiating.